# How to add render and create methods to Selectize element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I have a HTML 'select' element that I want to use as 'AutoSuggest' by using Selectize.js and this is how I initialize the selectize

```
 jQuery(ele).selectize({
                //options: initData,
                addPrecedence: false,
                persist: false,
                maxItems: 1,
                create: function (input) {
                    return {
                        value: input,
                        text: input
                    };
                },
                render: {
                    option_create: function (data, escape) {
                        return '<div class="create"><strong>' + escape(data.input) + '</strong></div>';
                    }
                }
            });
```

Now, the issue is if the 'ele' is already initialized as a 'Selectize' control without the 'render' and 'create' options, how can I add these options?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is how you do this

```
if (ele.selectize) {     
    var selectizeCtrl = jQuery(ele)[0].selectize;
                selectizeCtrl.settings.create = function (input) {
                    return {
                        value: input,
                        text: input
                    };
                };
                selectizeCtrl.settings.render.option_create = function (data, escape) {
                    return '<div class="create"><strong>' + escape(data.input) + '</strong></div>';
                };
}
```